# Where to put gradle dependencies block in kotlin native project generated by Intellij IDEA?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, tornadofx, kotlin-native

I'm trying to make my first app in Kotlin Native. I want to add TornadoFX to my freshly created project.
I need to add a dependency according to [TornadoFX guide](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/part1/2.%20Setting%20Up.html#gradle)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'no.tornado:tornadofx:x.y.z'
}
```

**The issue is - I cant figure out where exactly do I put it**.

This is my build.gradle contents (generated by IntelliJ IDEA):

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.3.60'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
kotlin {
    // For ARM, should be changed to iosArm32 or iosArm64
    // For Linux, should be changed to e.g. linuxX64
    // For MacOS, should be changed to e.g. macosX64
    // For Windows, should be changed to e.g. mingwX64
    mingwX64("mingw") {
        binaries {
            executable {
                // Change to specify fully qualified name of your application's entry point:
               entryPoint = 'sample.main'
                // Specify command-line arguments, if necessary:
                runTask?.args('')
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        // Note: To enable common source sets please comment out 'kotlin.import.noCommonSourceSets' property
        // in gradle.properties file and re-import your project in IDE.
        mingwMain {
        }
        mingwTest {
        }
    }
}

// Use the following Gradle tasks to run your application:
// :runReleaseExecutableMingw - without debug symbols
// :runDebugExecutableMingw - with debug symbols
```

Places I tried:

**1. top level**

`> Could not find method compile() for arguments [no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.19] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

**2. inside kotlin {}**

`> Could not find method compile() for arguments [no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.19] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

**3. inside mingwMain{}**

`> Could not find method compile() for arguments [no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.19] on object of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.DefaultKotlinDependencyHandler.`

Also, when put inside mingwMain, the compile line gets highlighted with a notice `'compile' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'`

Comment: Hello! You cannot use TornadoFX in the Native project, please have a look at [this](https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/issues/1116) issue in it's GH. This framework can be used only when you're targeting the JVM. To find applicable libraries, check [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mobilecrossplatform/) and [here](https://github.com/AAkira/Kotlin-Multiplatform-Libraries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was pointed out by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59198442/where-to-put-gradle-dependencies-block-in-kotlin-native-project-generated-by-int?noredirect=1#comment104634951_59198442) we cannot use TornadoFX in Kotlin Native, so I was doing everything wrong since the beginning, and this is not really a gradle issue.

Answer (score 3):

For the Kotlin multiplatform plugin, the dependency block should go into each source set. However, there is no type called `compile`. Rather, you can use `implementation` or one of the other types which you can read about in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#adding-dependencies).

Example:

```
sourceSets {
    mingwMain {
        dependencies {
            implementation 'no.tornado:tornadofx:x.y.z'
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, why are you using the Groovy DSL and not the Kotlin DSL if you are writing a Kotlin project? :-)